# Connect to AWS ES2 redis instance from another instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, node-redis

Two instance located in the same VPC and subnet
port in redis instance security group:
[image]

in /etc/redis/redis.conf      bind 0.0.0.0
but when

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';    
const host = 'ec2-some-digits.compute-1.amazonaws.com ';
const port = 6379; // Default Redis port
const client = createClient({ host, port });
```

i received

[image]

redis server:
[image]
and

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: don't open your security groups to 0.0.0.0/0.  It's really a lot more dangerous than you realize.  Weak passwords are a thing.  redis is not the kind of service that should be exposed to the wide world.  From the error message it says localhost so you may *think* you're using `host` to determine the redis server address, but your error message says otherwise.

Comment: I have tried to use in Inbound rules of redis instance the security group of nodejs instance but the result the same, of course you about security not connection, may be the reason secority group of nodejs connection?

Comment: did you read the error message or just screenshot and post it?  It clearly says `localhost`.

Comment: what I should change?  1.const host = 'ip-some-digits';  or add port in secutity group of nodejs instance?

Comment: I change to const client = createClient({  url: host, port: port });

Comment: But any value i used recieved  node server.js
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL

Comment: Looks like a  step in the right direction.  `host` should be the entirety of the value `'ec2-some-digits.compute-1.amazonaws.com'` with the right digits of course.  Your code has a space at the end of `host` which could cause `Invalid URL` that might be all it is

Comment: I remove empty space but it`s not resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

the reason in nodejs instance:
instead of

1. const host = 'ec2-some-digits.compute-1.amazonaws.com';
2. const client = createClient({ host, port });

you should use:

1. const host = 'redis://ec2-some-digits.compute-1.amazonaws.com';
2. const client = createClient({  url: host, port: port });